# Decoding an analogue signal for a given sampling and signal frequency that aren't in sync

Tags: sampling, digital-filters, analog-to-digital

I am trying to decode an analogue signal, that is intended to be converted to a digital one and decoded as USART communication.
[image]

In the image shown the blue trace is the analogue signal, and the filtered (using a moving-average filter) signal is shown in red. The signal shown is sampled at 1 MHz (thus 1 us), but has a USART baud rate of 115200bps (thus, one bit is received every 8.68 us, shown by the vertical green traces).

I am trying to successfully decode this message by considering the no. of bits per sample and an appropriate threshold voltage, of which to assign zeroes or ones. If I consider every 8th or 9th bit, I end up introducing errors into the digital signal. How does one process a signal when the sampling and message frequency aren't in sync?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the question does not belong in a digital signal processing realm. Still, you may benefit from my explanation and references below.

`The signal shown is sampled at 1 MHz (thus 1 us), but ... one bit is received every 8.68 us` means you are going to use your device in asynchronous mode. When using a piece of dedicated hardware ([UART chip, see UART models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#UART_models)), you typically delegate the synchronization task to the chip that you configurate according to the manufacturer's recommendations. Otherwise, you have the option to implement the protocol in software ([bit-banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#Application), where the code example transmits a byte of data on an SPI bus). For an implementation of a generic bit-bang UART driver, see, for example, github's entry [Codedraughtsman's bit-bang uart written in C](https://github.com/codedraughtsman/bit_bang_c_uart).